# facebook like button ref attribute does not send url parameter?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to implement the "ref or data-ref" attribute on facebook like buttons.  According to the documentation it will add a url parameter to the referrer URL when a person clicks a like button.  I have tried everything I can think of and cannot make it work. The like function works but it does not add the url parameter fb_ref=   as it is supposed to.  Any help is appreciated.

Note: i have also tried it like data-href="https://www.prizemagnet.com/share_test_2.php" data-ref="144141

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>This is a test please ignore</title>
</head>

<body>
This is a test for Prize Magnet.  Please ignore.

<fb:like href="https://www.prizemagnet.com/share_test_2.php" ref="144141"></fb:like>

</h1><script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1428051380756644";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that takes about ref?

Comment: [link]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: The FAQ say that when someone clicks a the like story that ref will be added. Not that that ref will be added when someone clicks the like button

Comment: You are right WizKid. To clarify I was checking the link from the Facebook Activity Log and not the actual story in the news feed.  I would mark your answer as correct but after an hour of trying to figure out how still can't figure out.  Not intuitive.